# How to apply customizable skins to an ASP.NET web site?

Tags: c#, asp.net, skin

I'm writing a SaaS application with a web front end written in ASP.NET.  I'm not much of a designer, and my ASP.NET knowledge is not yet at the expert level - I usually focus on server side stuff - but I have a basic master page and style sheets, which do the trick.

Now I want to offer my customers the ability to customize their web site with their own style sheets, colors, background pictures etc. so that their customers will log onto their portal at `mycustomer.mydomain.com` and see the skin that "mycustomer" has chosen.

Haven't the faintest clue how to do this.  How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are allowing the customer to specify his own CSS (either as a File or in some textBox in your Page). You can simply save it as a .css file in a virtual directory and During `Page_Load` or `Page_Init` Event add it to your page. You need to push a [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmllink.aspx) tag to Header of the page

Like this:

```
// Define an HtmlLink control.
HtmlLink myHtmlLink = new HtmlLink();
myHtmlLink.Href = "~/CustomersCustomStyleSheet.css";
myHtmlLink.Attributes.Add("rel", "stylesheet");
myHtmlLink.Attributes.Add("type", "text/css");

// Add the HtmlLink to the Head section of the page.
Page.Header.Controls.Add(myHtmlLink);
```

Comment: +1 Wow, that easy?  OK, so what does that do with my default stylesheet that's declared in the master page?  In case of conflict, how does the page know to use the custom stylesheet rather than the default?  And if you say you can only have one stylesheet - does that mean the customer has to provide stylesheet values for every attribute I've defined in my default stylesheet?

Comment: well yeah as a default behavior it will cascade both CSS and then apply it .. so this is something you will have to handle. You can do somthing like have `if`s to check if user has a custom one.. if he has then dont load your usual CSS keep a different CSS for that case which dosen't define style for Customizable styles and then load the user's CSS. Also you can Experiment with `!important`